# How should I place an object using Matter.Object.create in matter.js?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I'm using [matter.js](http://brm.io/matter-js/) and I have vertex data for objects with absolute positions (from SVG files). When I try to place them on the map, they **all end up positioned around 0, 0**. This is easily observable with this code snippet:

```
<body>
    <script src="matter-0.8.0.js"></script>

    <script>
     var engine = Matter.Engine.create(document.body);
     var object = Matter.Body.create( 
         { 
             vertices: [ { x: 300, y: 300 }, { x: 200, y: 300 }, { x: 350, y: 200 } ],
             isStatic: true
         });

     Matter.World.add(engine.world, [object]);
     Matter.Engine.run(engine);
    </script>
</body>
```

Or just look at this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vr213z4u/

**How is this positioning supposed to work?** Do I need to normalize the absolute position data into relative positions and use the position attribute of the options sent to Matter.Object.create? I tried that, but all objects got a little displaced, probably due to my lack of understanding.

**Update/clarification:**
My goal is that the vertices of the created object end up on exactly on the coordinates they have in the source data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At body creation the vertices are re-orientated about their center of mass and then translated to the given `body.position`. As you've not passed a position vector here this just defaults to (0, 0).

Try something like this:

```
var body = Matter.Body.create({
    position: { x: 500, y: 500 },
    vertices: [{ x: 300, y: 300 }, { x: 200, y: 300 }, { x: 350, y: 200 }],
    isStatic: true
});
```

If you want the position to be absolute:

```
var vertices = [{ x: 300, y: 300 }, { x: 200, y: 300 }, { x: 350, y: 200 }];

var body = Matter.Body.create({
    position: Matter.Vertices.centre(vertices),
    vertices: vertices,
    isStatic: true
});
```

Comment: Wohoo, an answer by the creator of matter.js! :) Thanks for the explanation, but by setting the position like that, won't the vertices end up on other coordinates than (300, 300), (200, 300) and (350, 200)? Se my updated question for a clarification.

Comment: Ah I see, I've updated my answer to show how you can do that!